# How to iterate over a vector of maps inc++

Tags: c++, vector

I would like to iterate over a vector which consists of a map. I would like to print the entries of the map.

```
    std::vector<ControlPointSet> cps
    std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t> control_points;
cps.push_back(ControlPointSet(range.x, color));
```

ControlPointSet looks like the following:

```
ControlPointSet(uint32_t range, const float3 &color_) : color(color_), gui_active(false), gui_h_active(false), gui_cp_drag(-1){
    control_points[0] = control_points[range -1] = 0;
}
```

How do I do that? Can anyone help me?

Comment: `How to iterate over a vector of maps` I don't see any vector of maps.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. How do I iterate over the vector cps which has entries of type ControlPointSet?

Comment: there is no relation between std::vector<ControlPointSet> and the std::map ? what's the relation between both the vector and the map ?

Comment: *How to iterate over a vector...* -- Is there an issue with simply using `std::for_each(cps.begin(), cps.end(), [] (ControPointSet& ps) { stuff_to_do_with_ps;});`?  Iteration doesn't require too much figuring out if you simply use `std::for_each`.

Comment: In general; `for (const auto& element : container) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a controlPointSet has
    range and color.

```
std::vector<ControlPointSet> cps
cps.push_back(ControlPointSet(range.x, color));
std::map<uint32_t, std::vector<ControlPointSet>> control_points;

control_points[0] = cps; // add key 0, with cps vector

// for each key value  pair in control_points map
for ( auto & key : control_points)
{
    uint32_t idx = key->first;
    uint32_t vec = key->second;
}
```